# Whether lead content readings follow a Normal distribution or not

Tags: distributions, self-study

> Studies indicated that drinking water supplied by some old lead-lined city piping systems contain harmful levels of lead. It appears that the distribution of lead content readings for individual water specimens has mean .033 mg/L and SD .10 mg/L.
>
> Explain why is it obvious that content readings are **not** normally distributed.

I cannot see the answer instantly. Why can't we perceive this distribution as normal with very high variance?

Comment: Well, the lead concentrations cannot be negative, right? But a normal distribution with mean $0.033$ and SD $0.10$ takes on values from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. The area of the normal distribution that is below $0$ is around $0.37$ (it would be a good idea to draw the normal distribution). So it only could be a truncated normal distribution.

Comment: @COOL That's a full answer, so why not post it as such?

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to note is that the lead concentration cannot be negative. Secondly, recall that the support of a [normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed) ranges from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

The best way to see why the lead concentration cannot be described by a normal distribution with mean $0.033$ mg/L and a standard deviation of $0.1$ mg/L is to draw it. The picture below depicts the PDF of such a normal distribution.

[image: PDF of normal density]

As you can see, a large proportion (i.e. $0.3707$) of the area is below zero (blue area). But this is impossible, as we noted above. We conclude that the readings cannot be modeled by a normal distribution. An alternative would be to truncate the normal distribution at $0$ which would lead to a [truncated normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution).